# How to fetch Webservice which takes string parameter?

Tags: react-native

*I  try to fetch webservice method. However, it takes string. How can I send string parameter to webservice ?*

I tried like this :

```
 fetch('url/MethodName', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
                      Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
            }),
        })
```

*where should I put string parameter ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by mozilla

```
var url = 'https://example.com/profile';
var data = {username: 'example'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log('Success:', JSON.stringify(response)))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

[send Json data as parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_JSON_data)

Comment: I tried to like this however it gives me {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

Comment: I send string like this:   body: JSON.stringify('CL_VA_Rihtim')

Comment: nop! you must send a paramer as dictionary JSON.stringify({'NameParameter':'value'})

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with fetch, but try to use Axios for making http requests

https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index